# QToolBox - Expanding multiple items

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I need something similar to a [`QToolBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtoolbox.html) with multiple expanding items / widgets that - as opposed to a `QToolBox` - supports displaying more than a single item at a time: When the user clicks on the item, it should expand; upon a second click, it should collapse: All, some or no items may be expanded at the same time.
Vertical scrollbars should be added if there is not enough space for all expanded items to be shown.

[image: Sample screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea / a solution how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solution for this problem I made a custom expanding widget with header and body when click on header body is hidden, combination of more expanding widgets and a spacer in a vertical layout you may have the same effect with `QToolbox`.

`expandwidget.h`:

```
#ifndef EXPANDWIDGET_H
#define EXPANDWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class ExpandWidgetHeader : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExpandWidgetHeader(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ExpandWidgetHeader();

signals:
    void headerClicked(bool hide);

private:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
    bool m_isHidden;
   // QLabel* headerTitle;

};

//================================================================
class ExpandWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExpandWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void hideBody(bool hide);

public:
    ExpandWidgetHeader *Header;
    QWidget *Body;

    };
#endif // EXPANDWIDGET_H
```

`expandwidget.cpp`:

```
#include "expandwidget.h"

ExpandWidget::ExpandWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #000000; background: #C4C4C1");

    setMinimumSize(QSize(330, 100));
    Header = new ExpandWidgetHeader(this);

    Body = new QWidget(this);
    Body->setGeometry(QRect(0, 25, 330, 100));

    connect(Header,SIGNAL(headerClicked(bool)),this,SLOT(hideBody(bool)));
}

void ExpandWidget::hideBody(bool hide)
{
    if (!hide)
    {
        Body->hide();
        this->setMinimumHeight(Header->height());
    }
    else
    {
        this->setMinimumHeight(Body->height()+Header->height());
        Body->show();
    }

}
//=========================================================================
ExpandWidgetHeader::ExpandWidgetHeader(QWidget *parent) :
    QLabel(parent)
{
    m_isHidden=false;
    this->setText("Text");
    this->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #000000; background: #898983");
    this->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 330, 25));
    this->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
}

ExpandWidgetHeader::~ExpandWidgetHeader()
{

}

void ExpandWidgetHeader::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (!m_isHidden)
    {
        emit headerClicked(m_isHidden);
    }
    else
    {
        emit headerClicked(m_isHidden);
    }
    m_isHidden = !m_isHidden;

}
```

Comment: Cool. I have been trying to use this and seems like I am lost how to apply this. Can you help me here with this?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you mean you don't want the tool box to show two items at the same time. i.e. If one item is expanded, all the other items should stay closed.

toolbox.h

```
#ifndef TOOLBOX_H
#define TOOLBOX_H

#include <QDialog>

#include <QToolBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class ToolBox : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ToolBox(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ToolBox();

private:
    QToolBox *toolBox;
    QLabel *label1;
    QLabel *label2;
    QLabel *label3;

};

#endif // TOOLBOX_H
```

toolbox.cpp

```
#include "toolbox.h"
#include "ui_toolbox.h"

ToolBox::ToolBox(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent) {
    label1 = new QLabel("first item");
    label2 = new QLabel("second item");
    label3 = new QLabel("third item");

    toolBox = new QToolBox;
    toolBox->addItem(label1, "page 1");
    toolBox->addItem(label2, "page 2");
    toolBox->addItem(label3, "page 3");

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(toolBox);

    setLayout(layout);
}

ToolBox::~ToolBox() {
    delete toolBox;
    delete label1;
    delete label2;
    delete label3;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "toolbox.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    ToolBox *window = new ToolBox;
    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: No, he didn't mean that. He wants to be able to expand multiple items at the same time, or collapse all of them.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the built-in Qt `QToolBox` does already ? Also, do you possibly mean _should collapse_ instead of _should stay closed_ ?