# QToolBox: how to have multiple items visible at the same time

Tags: qt

So far my QToolBox only alows me to have one element open/visible at the time.

How can the following be achieved? Is it possible by using a QToolBox?:
Please see the image, the arrows show what I mean.

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29315194. IMO, the screenshot is very helpful to illustrate the objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QToolBox` only supports one current (visible) item.

You could achieve what you wish with a `QTreeView` and a suitable model.

Comment: Do you have links to examples? or more details?

Comment: Qt comes with a boatload of examples, I'm sure there will be some for a treeview. Other than that, I don't know of any examples that do exactly what you want. The least you need to do is to understand Qt's model-view architecture, decide how to arrange the model, and go from there. It may turn out that you will need to tweak the view itself a bit too (by deriving from it or by copying `QTreeView`'s implementation and modifying the bits you need.